# issue doc to pdf using jodconverter library in spring-web-flux

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor, jodconverter

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to convert a document to PDF using the JodConverter library in a Spring WebFlux application. Does anyone have any suggestions?

> "timestamp": "2023-07-14T19:40:59.407+00:00", "status": 415, "error":
> "Unsupported Media Type", "trace":
> "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException:
> Content-Type 'application/msword' is not supported\n\tat

**Project:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.document.converter</groupId>
    <artifactId>document-converter</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>document-converter</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jodconverter</groupId>
            <artifactId>jodconverter-local</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jodconverter</groupId>
            <artifactId>jodconverter-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Central Maven repository</id>
            <name>Central Maven repository https</name>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>

    </repositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- ... -->
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>1.18.22</version>
                        <scope>runtime</scope>
                    </dependency>

                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Controller

```
package com.document.converter.controller;

import com.document.converter.service.ConverterService;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestPart;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers;

@RestController
public class ConverterController {
    private final ConverterService converterService;
    private final String PDF_FORMAT = "pdf";

    public ConverterController(ConverterService converterService) {
        this.converterService = converterService;
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/converter/v1/pdf", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<byte[]>> convert(@RequestPart("file") Mono<MultipartFile> filePart) {
        return filePart
                .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                .flatMap(converterService::convertToPdf)
                .map(convertedFile -> {
                    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
                    headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=output.pdf");
                    return ResponseEntity.ok()
                            .headers(headers)
                            .body(convertedFile);
                });
    }
}
```

service

```
package com.document.converter.service;

import org.jodconverter.core.DocumentConverter;
import org.jodconverter.core.document.DefaultDocumentFormatRegistry;
import org.jodconverter.core.document.DocumentFormat;
import org.jodconverter.core.office.OfficeException;
import org.jodconverter.core.office.OfficeManager;
import org.jodconverter.local.LocalConverter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

@Service
public class ConverterService {

    private final OfficeManager officeManager;

    public ConverterService(OfficeManager officeManager) {
        this.officeManager = officeManager;
    }

    public Mono<byte[]> convertToPdf(MultipartFile inputFile) {
        return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
            final DocumentFormat conversionTargetFormat =
                    DefaultDocumentFormatRegistry.getFormatByExtension("pdf");

            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            final DocumentConverter converter = LocalConverter.builder()
                    .officeManager(officeManager)
                    .build();

            try (InputStream inputStream = inputFile.getInputStream()) {
                converter
                        .convert(inputStream)
                        .to(outputStream)
                        .as(conversionTargetFormat)
                        .execute();
            } catch (IOException | OfficeException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed to convert the file.", e);
            }

            return outputStream.toByteArray();
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
    }
}
```

main class

```
package com.document.converter;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ServerProperties.class)
public class DocumentConverterApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DocumentConverterApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
server.port: 8083
jodconverter:
  local:
    enabled: true
    port-numbers: 2002
    kill-existing-process: true
    process-timeout: 250000
    process-retry-interval: 1000
    max-tasks-per-process: 200
    task-execution-timeout: 250000
    task-queue-timeout: 90000
    format-options:
      html:
        store:
          TEXT:
            FilterOptions: EmbedImages
```

i am testing it as below using postman ,

Url  `http://localhost:8083/converter/v1/pdf`
`Method : POST`
`Content-Type:multipart/form-data`
[image]

Detailed

any suggestions ?

Comment: Could you try to remove `Content-Type:multipart/form-data` header from your Postman request? Postman automatically sets the Content-Type to `multipart/form-data`, and it also adds a boundary in the Content-Type header, which is important for the server to correctly parse the request

Comment: I tried removing and testing, still getting same issue.   @YahorBarkouski